# Exchange username DOMAIN\USERNAME\MAILBOX deduced from an e-mail address

Tags: java, outlook, exchange-server

I'm trying to connect to MS Exchange using javax.mail.Store.

According to the following post [Connecting POP And IMAP Clients To MS Exchange Server](http://www.msexchange.org/articles-tutorials/exchange-server-5-5/Connecting_POP_And_IMAP_Clients_To_MS_Exchange_Server.html) the username has to be specified as DOMAIN\USERNAME\MAILBOX.

Is it possible to get the USERNAME and MAILBOX having only an e-mail address e.g name.surname@company.com and a preconfigured Outlook? I'm just wondering if I can find this information without a help of MS Exchange administrator.

Comment: You can probably look it up from AD via LDAP, but I don't know if you can always do that directly on the Exchange server or if you'd need to locate the domain controller first.

Comment: Thx for help. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find a solution.

Answer (score -1):

Would `substring()` help you? http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_substring.htm

I've never worked with Java so I'm afraid I can't give an example, but I've used PHP with `substr()`.

Comment: No, the problem is that the user name is independent of the address - it might be "bob.smith@contoso.com" but login "contoso\bsmith" or "contoso\bsmith2" because there's another B.Smith, or anything else.